# Proxmox: Good Idea to use LVM thin together with LVM-Caching

Tags: lvm, proxmox

I want to migrate my bare metal Debian server into Proxmox. My existing server uses a 120GB SSD and a 8 TB HDD. The HDD is cached on SSD (20G), which improves (read) performance a lot.

Here are all my logical volumes:

```
# lvs -a
  LV                     VG        Attr       LSize  Pool             Origin       Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  data-backup            backup-vg -wi-a----- <2,73t                                                                      
  data                   server-vg Cwi-aoC---  7,20t [lv_cache_cpool] [data_corig] 99,99  12,12           95,81           
  [data_corig]           server-vg owi-aoC---  7,20t                                                                      
  [lv_cache_cpool]       server-vg Cwi---C--- 20,00g                               99,99  12,12           95,81           
  [lv_cache_cpool_cdata] server-vg Cwi-ao---- 20,00g                                                                      
  [lv_cache_cpool_cmeta] server-vg ewi-ao---- 32,00m                                                                      
  [lvol0_pmspare]        server-vg ewi------- 32,00m                                                                      
  root                   server-vg -wi-ao---- 40,00g                                                                      
  swap                   server-vg -wi-ao----  2,00g                                                                      
  tmp                    server-vg -wi-ao----  9,31g                                                                      
  var                    server-vg -wi-ao---- 20,00g
```

Proxmox uses TVM-Thin for data storage (disks, snapshots, ISOs). The advantage of LVM-Thin is, that the partitions can exceed available disk space and snapshots are more efficient.

Now, i found out with `lvs -a` that LVM-thin also uses some kind of hidden LVs. But in contrast to my old setup, it not yet uses two disks.

```
# lvs -a
  LV               VG  Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  base-100-disk-0  pve Vri---tz-k  36.00g data                                               
  data             pve twi-aotz-- 337.86g             1.02   0.52                            
  [data_tdata]     pve Twi-ao---- 337.86g                                                    
  [data_tmeta]     pve ewi-ao----  <3.45g                                                    
  [lvol0_pmspare]  pve ewi-------  <3.45g                                                    
  root             pve -wi-ao----  96.00g                                                    
  swap             pve -wi-ao----   8.00g                                                    
  vm-100-cloudinit pve Vwi-a-tz--   4.00m data        0.00                                   
  vm-101-disk-0    pve Vwi-aotz-- 112.00g data        0.00
```

What you can see here is the base installation of Proxmox on a 500GB SSD plus two created VMs.

Anybody knows what the LVs in square braces are?

I wonder if I can attach LVM-Cache, too? But does this interfere with the existing hidden partitions? It's clear that this is a custom set-up and it would be difficult to managa via GUI.

That's why I ask if it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it out and it seems to work. Hence, the Cache is added to data_tdata, not to data itself.

```
# lvs -a
  LV                       VG     Attr       LSize   Pool               Origin             Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  vzdump                   backup -wi-ao----  <1.82t                                                                              
  base-100-disk-0          pve    Vri---tz-k  36.00g data                                                                         
  data                     pve    twi-aotz--   7.50t                                       22.37  7.81                            
  [data_cache_cpool]       pve    Cwi---C---  30.00g                                       0.00   12.12           0.00            
  [data_cache_cpool_cdata] pve    Cwi-ao----  30.00g                                                                              
  [data_cache_cpool_cmeta] pve    ewi-ao----  32.00m                                                                              
  [data_tdata]             pve    Cwi-aoC---   7.50t [data_cache_cpool] [data_tdata_corig] 0.00   12.12           0.00            
  [data_tdata_corig]       pve    owi-aoC---   7.50t                                                                              
  [data_tmeta]             pve    ewi-ao----   8.33g                                                                              
  [lvol0_pmspare]          pve    ewi-------   8.33g                                                                              
  root                     pve    -wi-ao----  96.00g                                                                              
  swap                     pve    -wi-ao----   8.00g                                                                              
  vm-100-cloudinit         pve    Vwi-a-tz--   4.00m data                                  0.00                                   
  vm-101-disk-1            pve    Vwi-aotz--  <2.73t data                                  60.26                                  
  vm-101-disk-2            pve    Vwi-aotz-- 112.00g data                                  28.01                                  
  vm-103-disk-0            pve    Vwi-aotz--   2.00g data                                  24.20
```

Cache is working

```
dmsetup status /dev/mapper/pve-data_tdata
0 16106127360 cache 8 993/8192 128 29/491520 0 0 26 53 0 29 0 3 metadata2 writethrough no_discard_passdown 2 migration_threshold 2048 smq 0 rw -
```